# Using QT VC tool for CMake project

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, qt5

[image]My project is a platform independent one where I use CmakeList to generate sln file for visual studio. I am able to build, debug and run in visual studio but qml files I am not able to keep debug statements. For this I installed "QT VC tool" but I don't know how to use it for already building project in visual studio.

Can someone please help on this